# Tag name for Amnesia: A machine for pigs?

Tags: discussion, tags

Its a little too long to be [amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs). For now I have it at [amnesia-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-machine-for-pigs) (dropping the 'a'), but other options could be [a-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-machine-for-pigs) or something else.

Comment: I suggest dropping the "a", search engines usually ignore "a" as a word anyway

Comment: There are people referring to it as machine for pigs and as amfp on the steam community page, so no real consensus there

Answer (score 17):

Currently we are using [amnesia-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-machine-for-pigs).

Comment: I like this best.  No reason we couldn't synonymize `amnesia-amfp` and `a-machine-for-pigs` to it.

Answer (score 1):

**The tag name is now [amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs).**

Since the tag length was [increased to 35 characters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've went ahead and retagged three questions with the full title.

Answer (score -5):

We could use [amnesia-amfp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-amfp). We use initialism for several sequel tags for much the same reasons, and we could do the same.

Comment: No reason to do that when we don't have to.