# Expand tags for Amnesia game series

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The following tags can be expanded thanks to the 35 character tag name limit:

- [amnesia-dark-descent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-dark-descent) → [amnesia-the-dark-descent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-the-dark-descent)
- [amnesia-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-machine-for-pigs) → [amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs)

There was a previous discussion named [Tag name for Amnesia: A machine for pigs?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7653/47878), with the resolution to use [amnesia-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-machine-for-pigs) due to the 25 character tag name limit at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds good. Merges completed:

- [amnesia-dark-descent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-dark-descent) → [amnesia-the-dark-descent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-the-dark-descent)
- [amnesia-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-machine-for-pigs) → [amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs)